# How do use multiple subquery within left joins to retrieve connecting data points

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join

Hi having some issues with my code not sure what is meant by missing keywords.

```
SELECT  a.equipment_id, a.equipment_description, a.failure_class,
        b.equipment_display_mapping_id,
        c.equipment_display_category_name,
        d.link_id, d.location_id,
        e.rd_attr_txt, e.node_fr_id_num, e.node_to_id_num,
        f.node_to_id_num as Previous_node
FROM Equipment_Detail a
LEFT JOIN equipment_display_mapping b on b.equipment_id = a.equipment_id
LEFT JOIN equipment_display_category c on c.equipment_display_category_id =  b.equipment_display_category_id
LEFT JOIN equipment_location_mapping d on d.equipment_id = a.equipment_id
LEFT JOIN vw_gis_link e on e.lk_id_num = d.link_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT node_to_id_num 
        FROM vw_bis_link_details
        WHERE node_to_id_num = e.node_fr_id_num
    ) as f on d.link_id = f.link_id
WHERE 1=1 and a.equipment_type_id = 113;
```

getting the following error:

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you join using link_id but you only select the node_to_id_num. Also in Oracle if I remeber correctly you cannot use AS when aliasing tables. So substitue `as f` with  `f`

```
(
    SELECT node_to_id_num 
    FROM vw_bis_link_details
    WHERE node_to_id_num = e.node_fr_id_num
) f on d.link_id = f.link_id
```